# Data protected in getting data

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, n-tier-architecture

My question is about protecting data and creating a smart architecture for the following purpose.
I have a LibraryBS class(there are a lot of such type classes) that gets data from the database. The LibraryBS class has GETALL() and GetById(int libraryId) functions. GETALL gets all libraries and GetById gets only one library from the database which's Id=libraryId. This is a web application that uses these classes. 
Now I want to add Company Protection. It means when the user logins the system and uses the LibraryBs.GetAll(), the user can see only the data that belongs the user's company.
There are also specific users (let's call super user) when this type of user enters the system they can see all data.

What type patterns do you recommend?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Considering the table of Library, it should contain column companyId and another table User which has companyId as foreign key.
May be you can add a column 'Access' in User table.

There will be lookup table for 'Access' column with data

```
Id AccessLevel
0  Undefined
1  User
2  Company


User Table
Id  Name Access CompanyId
1   Bob  1      1
1   Jon  2      2
```

So when you fetch data say user Bob, you can create where clause dynamically based on Access for that user.

Answer (score 0):

You need a user table that stores users with a reference key or foreign key to company table that stores company details and an Access Level table that stores the user access levels with foreign key references to both use and company and a column representing the access level per user per company. You would also need to include a reference in your Library table back to company.

With this in place you need to make the LibraryBS.GetAll method take user object as a parameter.

With this in place your GetAll method can work out the correct library to get depending on the user passed in.

Hope this helps.